# How do i search for a line of text in whole text file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file, hash

How do I read every line of a file in Python and check if that line is in another one of the lines of the same text?

I've created hash of 2000 images and stored it in the same text file. So to find if the duplicate image exists I want to cross-check hash of all the images generated.

Below is the code in list in which I have extracted the data,

`with open('hash_info.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()`

> `['fbefcfdf961f1919\n', 'aecc9e9696961f2f\n', 'cc1c9c9c1c1e272f\n', 'a4ce9e9e9793134b\n', 'e2e7e7e7e7e7e763\n', 'e64fcbcfcf8f0f27\n', '9c1c3c3c3e1e1e9c\n', 'c8cc9cb43e3c3b1b\n', 'cccd9e9e9e1e1f9f\n', 'ccce9e9e9ece0e4e\n', 'a6a7cbcfcf071736\n', 'f69c9c3c3636373b\n', 'ec9c9cbc3c26272b\n', 'f0cccc9c8c0e3f3b\n', '4c9c363e3e3e1e5d\n', '9c9cbc3e3c3c376f\n', 'f5ccce9e9e9e1f2c\n', 'cccc8c9ccc9ccdca\n', 'dc98ac2c363e5e5f\n', 'f2e7e7e7e7e76746\n', '9a9a1e3e3e3e373f\n', 'cc8c9e9e8ecece8f\n', 'db9f9f1e363e9e9e\n', 'e4cece8e9ececfcf\n', 'cecede9f9bce8f8f\n', 'b8ce4e4e9f1b1b29\n', 'ece6e6e7efcf0d05\n', 'cd8e9696b732163f\n', 'cece9e9ecececfcd\n', 'cc9d9f9f9f8dcdd9\n', '992d2c2c3c3ebe9e\n', 'e6e6cece8f2d2939\n', 'eccfcfcfcf4f6f7d\n', 'e6cecfcfcfefcec6\n', 'edf8e4cecece4e0e\n', 'e9d6e6e7e7a76667\n', 'edcecfcfcfcfcecf\n', 'a5a6c6ce8e0f43c7\n', '3a3e7c7c3d3e3f2f\n', 'cc9c963c361f173f\n', '8c9c9c9d9d9d1a9a\n', 'f0cc8e9e9e9f9d9e\n', '989c3c3c1c2e6e5b\n', 'f0989c1c9e1e1adb\n', 'f09c9c9c9c9e9e9f\n', 'e6ce4e1e86333309\n', 'a6cece9e8f0f0f2f\n', 'e8cccc9cccdc8d8c\n', 'f0ecced6969f0f2d\n', 'e0d89c3c3c3d3d1f\n', 'e6e7c7cfc7c64e4f\n', 'a6cf4b0f0e073739\n', 'cececececccf4b5b\n', 'a6c6cfcfcfc6c6c6\n', 'f0fcf3e3e3e3f303\n', 'f9f2e7e7cbcfcf97\n','fbefcfdf961f1919\n', 'f3e7e5e5e7e5c7c3\n', 'b3e7e7c7c7070f1e\n', 'cb9d97963e3f3325\n', '9b1e2c1c1e1e2e2b\n', '9d9e969f9f9f9f0f\n', 'e6a7a7e7e666666c\n', 'c64e9e9b0b072727\n','fbefcfdf961f1919\n', 'c7cfcfcfcfc7ce86\n', 'e6cecfcfcfc7c745\n', 'e6e6cecececfcfcf\n', 'cbcd9f9f9e1f3a7a\n', 'ccce9ecececec646\n', 'f1c7cfdf9f970325\n', '989d9c1c1e9e9f1f\n', '9c9e1c1e9e9d9c9a\n', '5f3d7656de5d3b1f\n', '5f3d76565e5d3b1f\n']`

Below is the text file of the same as above:

`33393cccde1b3f7b
71fb989ed79f3b79
78b0a3a34c7c3737
67781c5e9fcc1f4c
313c2ccf4b5f5f7f
ece8cc9c9696171f
f4ec8c9c9c9c1e1e
e8cc94b68c9c1ece
d89c36161c9c1e3f
ecccdacececf6d6d
a4cecbcacf87173d
f9f3e7ebcbc74707
d9e5c7cbd34b4f4d
e4ece6e3cbdb8f1d
ccde9a9ecccecfad
e6e6ced293d6cfc6
cc8c9c989ccc8e8b
f2ccc696cecfcfcf
cc8c9a9a9ececfcd
cc9c9c9cdc9c9ff3`

**How I solved it**

```
def check_dup(hash):

    f = open('hash_text_file.txt')
    s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access = mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    if s.find(hash.rstrip()) != -1: #rstrip to remove \n
            print("Duplicate Image")
            return False
    else:
            return True
```

Comment: Happy Coding. SO is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Start with reading the file in a set for fast comparison ... after providng code, please add some lines of your save file as well (text, not screenshots)

Comment: @PatrickArtner fixed it. But how do you move a Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Opens the text document    
file=open("Old.txt", "r")
#Reads the text document and splits it into a list with each line being an element
lines=file.read().split("\n")
new_lines=[]
#Iterate over list of lines
for line in lines:
    #If line is not in the empty list of lines( i.e the list that will contain unique lines) add the line to it
    #This makes sure that no line exists twice in the list
    if line not in new_lines:
        new_lines.append(line)
#Open a new text file
file_new=open("New.txt","w")
#Add each line of our new unique lines list to the text file
file_new.write("\n".join(new_lines))
file_new.close()
file.close()
```

Comment: Could you use comments and elaborate it

Comment: I added comments if anything feels unclear make sure to point it out

Answer (score 0):

I took some of your sample data and cleaned the "\n" from it, converted to set and testing them for in/not in set like this:

```
data = ['fbefcfdf961f1919\n', 'aecc9e9696961f2f\n', 'cc1c9c9c1c1e272f\n', 
        'a4ce9e9e9793134b\n', 'e2e7e7e7e7e7e763\n',]

# create a set from your data, lookups are faster that way 
cleaned = set(x.strip("\n") for x in data) 

for testMe in ['not in it', 'fbefcfdf961f1919']: # supply your list of "new" things
    if testMe in cleaned:
        print "Got a duplicate: " + testMe 
    else:
        print "Unique: " + testMe   
        # append to hash-file
        with open("hash_info.txt","w+") as f: # if you have 1000 new hashes this
            f.write(testMe+"\n")  # reopens the file 1000 times (see below)
```

To compare huge new data to your existing data you should put the new data in a set as well:

```
newSet = set( ... your data here ... )
```

and use `set` operations to get all that are not yet in your `cleaned` set:

```
thingsToAddToFile = newSet - cleaned    # substracts from newSet all known ones, only 
                                        # new ones will be in thingsToAddToFile  

# add them all to your exisitng ones by appending them:
with open("hash_info.txt","w+") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(thingsToAddToFile) + "\n") # joins all in set and appends `'\n'` on end
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html:

> ```
> x in s                            test x for membership in s
> x not in s                        test x for non-membership in s
> s.issubset(t)           s <= t    test whether every element in s is in t
> s.issuperset(t)         s >= t    test whether every element in t is in s
> s.union(t)              s | t     new set with elements from both s and t
> s.intersection(t)       s & t     new set with elements common to s and t
> s.difference(t)         s - t     new set with elements in s but not in t
> s.symmetric_difference(t) 
>                         s ^ t     new set with elements in either s or t but not both
> ```

Comment: Why use ' not in it' ?

What I am saying is that each line should be checked with all the lines in my text file.

Comment: @DanishKhan  You have all your files worht of hashes inside the set `cleaned`. With `if 'somevalue' not in cleaned: .... do smth ... ` you have testet if it is anywhere in your file. If NOT so, simply add it to the file.